# Why not persist the join table in a many-to-many relationship when declare @Transaction in test method?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Why don't persist the join table in a many-to-many relationship when declare @Transaction in test method?

Below is my entity class code.

When I declare @Transaction, Hibernate insert values into the join table. However, if I do not declare it, do not insert it.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class ParentEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String parentValue;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<ChildEntity> childs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class ChildEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "child_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String childValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private ParentEntity parentEntity;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "child_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", nullable = false)
    )
    private Set<TagEntity> tags;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tag")
public class TagEntity {

    @Column(name = "tag_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long tagId;

    @Column
    String value;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private List<ChildEntity> childs;
}
```

@Transactional O

```
Hibernate: insert into parent (parent_value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into child (child_value, parent_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into child (child_value, parent_id) values (?, ?)
```

@Transcational X

```
Hibernate: insert into parent (parent_value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into child (child_value, parent_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into tag (value) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into child (child_value, parent_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into child_tag (child_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into child_tag (child_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into child_tag (child_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)
```

Below is my test code.

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public class TestRepository {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    public void saveParent(ParentEntity parent) {
        em.persist(parent);
    }
}


@Autowired
TestRepository repository;

@Test
@Transactional // @Transactional
    public void test() {
        ParentEntity parentEntity = new ParentEntity();
        parentEntity.setParentValue("parent value");

        ChildEntity childEntity1 = new ChildEntity();
        childEntity1.setChildValue("child1 value");

        ChildEntity childEntity2 = new ChildEntity();
        childEntity2.setChildValue("child2 value");

        TagEntity tagEntity = new TagEntity();
        tagEntity.setValue("tag1 value");

        TagEntity tagEntity2 = new TagEntity();
        tagEntity.setValue("tag2 value");

        TagEntity tagEntity3 = new TagEntity();
        tagEntity.setValue("tag3 value");

        Set<TagEntity> tags1 = new HashSet<>();
        tags1.add(tagEntity);
        tags1.add(tagEntity2);

        Set<TagEntity> tags2 = new HashSet<>();
        tags1.add(tagEntity2);
        tags1.add(tagEntity3);

        childEntity1.setTags(tags1);
        childEntity2.setTags(tags2);

        tagEntity.setChilds(Collections.singletonList(childEntity1));
        tagEntity2.setChilds(Arrays.asList(childEntity1, childEntity2));
        tagEntity3.setChilds(Collections.singletonList(childEntity2));

        childEntity1.setParentEntity(parentEntity);
        childEntity2.setParentEntity(parentEntity);

        parentEntity.getChilds().add(childEntity1);
        parentEntity.getChilds().add(childEntity2);

        repository.saveParent(parentEntity);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`EntityManager.persist()` is a "logical" operation and does not mandatory trigger the insert statements.

Only flush() and a transaction commit triggers the execution of the SQL statements.

So if you want have no transaction commit and see all insert statement you have to call `EntityManager.flush()`

Comment: I realized that the foundation is important because of you. Thank you very much.